# How to Search for Nested Styles with &-- Syntax in IDE?

Tags: search, sass, nested, vscode-extensions, code-search

How to search for nested styles in your IDE/VS Code (for example when using &-- syntax)? Example:

```
.my-component {
  &--modifier {
    // Styles for the modifier
  }
}
```

I can't search `my-component--modifier` in my IDE's search input... nothing shows up. Is there an extension I can use so they do display? Or a search pattern I can apply? No idea..

Things I tried: Installed couple extensions, looked into VS Code's search patterns documentions to see if I can find any information.. no luck

Thanks!